# read XML from PHP to pass in to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, xml

Can I pass an xml file to JavaScript by PHP like this:

```
     <?php
        $xmlDoc = new DOMDocument('1.0');
        $xmlDoc->formatOutput = true;
        $xmlDoc->load("customer.xml");
        echo $xmlDoc->saveXML();
        $strXml = $xmlDoc->saveXML(); 
        return $strXml;
        ?>
```

when I try to do this I get `null` in the server response in this line in JavaScript

```
var serverResponse = xHRObject.responseXML;
```

but,

```
     var spantag = document.getElementById("example").innerHTML = 
        xHRObject.responseText;
```

will print out the information and also `prompt(spantag);` will prompt the whole xml document. But I want to use the tag names. So that I need to use

```
var header = serverResponse.getElementsByTagName("book");
```

but this gives me an error since the `xHRObject.responseXML` is null. Please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
var xHRObject = false;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{xHRObject = new XMLHttpRequest();}
else if (window.ActiveXObject)
{xHRObject = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");}
function validate(){
    xHRObject.open("GET", "login.php", true);
    xHRObject.onreadystatechange =test;
    xHRObject.send(null); }
function test(){
    if ((xHRObject.readyState == 4) &&(xHRObject.status == 200))
        {var serverResponse = xHRObject.responseXML;
        var header = serverResponse.getElementsByTagName("customer");
        var spantag = document.getElementById("err")= xHRObject.responseText;}}
```

I can output via the prompt the span tag it'll give me a xml file but when I output serverResponse it'll give a null. that means responseText have a value but response xml doesn't.

Customer.xml has customers as the main tag and then I have added two customers in a customer tag. then firstname surname email tags are there.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `echo $xmlDoc` instead of a simple return, which doesn't actually generate any content. Passing it VIA an ajax call (which I'm assuming you are) requires that you echo or print some content on the called page.

Comment: I'm trying to print it using javascript not with the php. I just want to get the values to javascript through the php. However I tried what you told it still gave the same error.

Comment: I'd need more code to go on to give a more thorough answer.

Comment: If you could expand on the code: I.E. What file is the PHP in? Where is the JavaScript located? Are you attempting to supply the XML inside the same file as you're attempting to manipulate it with the javascript? Or are you attempting to use an AJAX call to retrieve the XML from a different file?

Comment: I have everything in one folder. customer.xml is in the same folder. I extended my question please help me in this.

Comment: rest of the file names are login.htm login.js login.php

Comment: What you're trying to do, it appears, is load the XML inside the same file as you're running the JavaScript. Unfortunately, you're also using AJAX methods for this. The confusion is that you would need to load the XML in it's own file, and access that information VIA an Ajax call. The PHP code looks fine, with the echoing out of the XML file. Now if you just nail down how to get the JavaScript ajax call you'll be golden. Look into jQuery, it's the simplest framework I've found, and will make your life easier.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I can't use jQuery for this.

I found the answer to the question. Actually some one taught me the problem was in my php file. I had to add the header text to that:

```
header('Content-Type: text/xml');
```

Comment: Would you please show your completed script to pass XML from PHP to JS?